# Are these dishwasher symptoms consistent with a blocked drainage hose?

Tags: dishwasher

I believe that my dishwasher's drainage hose is partially blocked. Are the following symptoms all consistent with / explained by that, or is there something else I should be worried about?

- **Not fully draining**

  - After a wash there is normally an inch or two of pretty clean water left lying at the bottom of the dishwasher.
  - Doesn't seem like dirty washing water - seems more like rinsing water. Hence my suspicion that the blockage is only partial.
- **Drastically increased salt usage**

  - Previously a salt-refill would "last" 3-5 months. It's now asked for 4 refills in a month.
  - I'm guessing this is caused by the water not draining, which means the salt reservoir sits underwater the whole time?
- **Rust spots on cutlery**

  - Dishwasher has a top cutlery drawer and knifes have recently started coming out with notable rust spots, where they didn't previously do so.
- **Glasses with greasy streaks**
- **Less effective cleaning in general**

I've followed the manual's instructions about cleaning the filter, and checking that the impeller wheel is unobstructed, to no effect. ([Manual, page 27/28](https://media3.bosch-home.com/Documents/9000843996_D.pdf)) So I think it's in the pipe itself, not in the dishwasher?

Have I judged this correctly?

---

See [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/141064/is-it-safe-to-put-drain-cleaner-down-a-washing-machine) for my question about what I should do if I *am* right.

Answer (score 1):

Where does your dishwasher drain hose go? It should go to either an **air gap** or a **high hose loop**. An air gap is a metal/plastic gadget, normally on top of the sink, that has the dishwasher output come in one hose and another hose that goes down to sink drain/disposal. A high hose loop has one hose that goes from the dishwasher, loops up to just under the counter (and at a minimum, above the bottom of the sink) and then goes down to the sink drain/disposal.

If you have a high hose loop but it fell down then that would explain at least some of these symptoms. If you're not sure, post a picture of the hose/drain/etc.

The manual you linked is for use, not installation. I found a Bosch installation manual and while it does not include a diagram of a high hose loop connection, it does reference that in the text, so that is definitely a possibility - and therefore a "high hose loop that isn't high or a loop any more" is also a possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I don't recognise the description of the air gap, so I'll take a look for the high hose loop, tonight.